# Problema regex java selenium en un string

Tags: java, regex, selenium

Estoy automatizando pruebas en java con selenium utilizando webDriver. Dado que a veces no se me muestran las mismas pantallas, necesito la creación de una regex para poder localizar mis elementos. He buscado varias soluciones con regex pero ni las más sencillas me funcionan. A continuación indico el localizador y las distintas expresiones utilizadas

Elemento visualizado real: `driver.findElement(By.id("mobile.android.dev:id/bt_config")).isDisplayed()`

Expresion regular utilizada 1 : `driver.findElement(By.id("mobile.android.dev:id/bt_a-zA-Z0-9._-]*")).isDisplayed()`

Expresion regular utilizada 2 : `driver.findElement(By.id("mobile.android.dev:id/bt_confi[a-z]")).isDisplayed()`

La idea es incluir esta expresion en un If para detectar el elemento que se me visualiza. Como se puede ver, he realizado varias pruebas por si en alguna de ellas era correcta, pero incluso la expresión más simple me está fallando, no me reconoce las opciones con expresion regular aunque la que tiene todo el String sin expresion regular, me la reconoce como `true`. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Hay alguna otra posibilidad?

Nota : Todas las pruebas están realizadas haciendo debug.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo tu id es algo como "bt_config<cualquier_cosa_variable>", pero siempre inicia con bt_config. Usa css.

```
id^=bt_config
```